# Generate a vector of predetermined numbers

Tags: vector, octave

I simply have to generate in Octave a 1xn vector of predetermined numbers.
I have to generate a 1xn random sequence of 0.7 and 1.8. How can I do it?

Comment: If they are random, then they are not "predetermined". Of course, pseudo-random is different. Regardless, why not try something! Make an effort.

Answer (score 0):

I take it by "a random sequence of 0.7 and 1.8" you mean every entry is either 0.7 or 1.8 each with probability 0.5

For this you can do:

```
r = rand(1,n);
v = zeros(1,n);
v(r < 0.5) = 0.7;
v(r >= 0.5) = 1.8;
```